# Stripe Payments API you have to change the one declared in the console but I can't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, stripe-payments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPEV4.jpg)

problem declared in console but i don't know what to do exactly to fix it, it's a stripe api for payment, first time i use it. What do I change?

Answer (score 1):

did you update the version of your Stripe SDK ? It apparently ask you to migrate from line_items to create products and prices. If you look the documentation your code should look like on this image.
(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices)

[image]

Comment: yes I have seen the documentation, leaving out some differences that I have made with the map, I don't find what I should solve. what would you modify?

Comment: In your code I can see that you left description in line_items (line 7) which is deprecated

Comment: solved: D I put items.description instead of item, then it gave me error on line 21 deprecated shipping_rates and to put shipping_options, so I did and from invalid object. For now I have commented on it so much it is not essential. A thousand thanks